# Cutting a piece of text in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I need cut a piece of text fragment starting with `"<div"`.

I have some like this:

```
$query = mysql_query("Select * from products_description");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
    $usun = substr($row['products_description'], 0, strpos($row['products_description'], "<div"));
    mysql_query('UPDATE products_description SET products_description = '.$usun.' WHERE products_id = '.$row['products_id'].'');

}
```

Unfortunately it does not work

Comment: Please specify what you mean by "does not work". Please include some brief examples of input and current vs. expected output.

Comment: do you mean to say that you have HTML in your db?

Comment: It's also possible it does not work at all because you're using a database extension that has been removed from PHP.

Comment: @Don'tPanic Uh-ha! I didn't even think of that. God knows which version of php he is using...

Answer (score 1):

If we echo out the SQL text (the UPDATE statement the code is attempting to execute), we'd see part of the problem.

String literals need to be enclosed in single quotes.

```
... SET products_description = 'string literal' WHERE ...
                               ^              ^
```

Another issue is that we don't see any guarantee that the string literal value isn't going to include potentially unsafe values, such as a single quote. Potentially unsafe values should be properly escaped before they are included in SQL text.

Of course, if we used a *prepared statement* with *bind placeholders*, we would entirely avoid both of those problems.

---

Assuming that the PHP `substr` function is returning the value you want assigned to the column... there's really no need to process RBAR (row by agonizing row), when we could accomplish the same thing in one swoop.

```
 UPDATE mytable SET mycol = SUBSTRING_INDEX(mycol,'<div',1) ;
```

We can test our expressions in a SELECT statement, before we commit to running an UPDATE statement. For example:

```
SELECT t.mycol 
     , SUBSTRING_INDEX(t.mycol,'<div',1) AS newval
  FROM mytable t
```

Comment: I thought about using SUBSTRING_INDEX, but I thought it would also modify values where `<div` might appear in the middle of the string rather than at the beginning. Is that a valid concern, or am I misunderstanding how it works?

Comment: @Don'tPanic: SUBSTRING_INDEX returns the portion of the string up to the specified delimiter. The function will return an empty string if the delimiter is the first character(s) of the string. My usage of SUBSTRING_INDEX was intended to replicate the PHP expression in the OP code (return the portion of the string up to the first occurrence of `'<div'`)  `$s = substr($s,0,strpos($s,'<div'));`  (Maybe I'm not understanding what the OP expression is supposed to achieve.)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That makes sense. I didn't read the question closely enough and relied too much on my assumption of what they were trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, use PDO rather than mysqli_ or mysql_ functions. Then you can use parameter binding. It helps to prevent SQL injection.

You should quote your `$usun` before concatenating it into the SQL request:

```
$usun=mysql_real_escape_string($usun);
```

Comment: what does that have to do with what they asked/posted?

Comment: I have product descriptions in the database. In each of them there is a superfluous description starting with <div. I want to remove it in each product.

Comment: @DamianZiołecki then your original code will work. I cant see anything wrong with it. If you want to get help, post your full code, and the data in the database.

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear why the exact code in your question isn't working, (although the quoting issue others have pointed out is definitely part of the problem) but this may answer the question anyway since I'm proposing something completely different.

Try just doing one update query to remove the `<div` at the beginning of the string instead of the select/loop/update approach.

```sql
UPDATE products_description
SET products_description = SUBSTRING(products_description FROM 5)
WHERE products_description LIKE '<div%'
```

Or if you want to remove everything *after* the `<div`:

```sql
UPDATE products_description
SET products_description = '<div'
WHERE products_description LIKE '<div%'
```

Comment: products_description => "Some text <div style="font-weight: bold;"><p>More text... asd asd asd asd ad a </p></div>" I need delete all text after <div...

Comment: @DamianZiołecki so, what are you trying to remove from it? Then entire `<div>` tag? What about the closing `</div>`?

Comment: @DamianZiołecki all text after `<div`? So you want to be left with just `<div`? It would really help if you could edit your question to include an example of one of the current values, and what you want it to be after the update. I feel like I'm still not completely getting it.